# How to set "targets" in creating ALB in CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

**Current Code**

```js
import * as elasticloadbalancingv2 from "@aws-cdk/aws-elasticloadbalancingv2";
.
.
.

target: ec2.Instance

const targetGroups = new elasticloadbalancingv2.ApplicationTargetGroup(this, "TargetGroup", {
  healthCheck: {
    path: "/",
    port: "80",
    protocol: elasticloadbalancingv2.Protocol.HTTP
  },
  port: 80,
  protocol: elasticloadbalancingv2.ApplicationProtocol.HTTP,
  targets: [new elasticloadbalancingv2.IpTarget(target.instancePrivateIp)],
  targetType: elasticloadbalancingv2.TargetType.IP,
  vpc,
})
```

**Problem**

This code is working but `IpTarget` is [deprecated](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-elasticloadbalancingv2.IpTarget.html).

I cannot understand how to replace it.

How do you make it work without using any deprecated class?

---

**Fixed Code**

```js
    import * as elasticloadbalancingv2 from "@aws-cdk/aws-elasticloadbalancingv2";
    import * as elasticloadbalancingv2targets from "@aws-cdk/aws-elasticloadbalancingv2-targets";

    .
    .
    .

    const pgAdminTarget: elasticloadbalancingv2targets.InstanceIdTarget[] = [];
    pgAdminTarget.push(new elasticloadbalancingv2targets.InstanceIdTarget(props.instance.instanceId, 80));

    const pgAdminTg = new elasticloadbalancingv2.ApplicationTargetGroup(this, "TargetGroup", {
      healthCheck: {
        path: "/health.html",
        port: "80",
        protocol: elasticloadbalancingv2.Protocol.HTTP
      },
      port: 80,
      protocol: elasticloadbalancingv2.ApplicationProtocol.HTTP,
      targetType: elasticloadbalancingv2.TargetType.INSTANCE,
      targets: [pgAdminTarget],
      vpc,
    })

    const alb = new elasticloadbalancingv2.ApplicationLoadBalancer(this, "ALB", {
      vpc,
      internetFacing: true,
      loadBalancerName: "ec2-alb",
      vpcSubnets: { subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC },
    });

    alb.addListener("lister", {
      certificates: [certificate],
      defaultTargetGroups: [pgAdminTg],
      port: 443,
      protocol: elasticloadbalancingv2.ApplicationProtocol.HTTPS,
    });
```

**New Error**

> Property 'attachToApplicationTargetGroup' is missing in type 'InstanceIdTarget[]' but required in type 'IApplicationLoadBalancerTarget'.
> targets: [pgAdminTarget],

> node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-elasticloadbalancingv2/lib/alb/application-target-group.d.ts:291:5
> 291     attachToApplicationTargetGroup(targetGroup: IApplicationTargetGroup): LoadBalancerTargetProps;
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> 'attachToApplicationTargetGroup' is declared here.

According to [the document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-elasticloadbalancingv2-targets.InstanceIdTarget.html#attachwbrtowbrapplicationwbrtargetwbrgrouptargetgroup), `attachToApplicationTargetGroup` is called automatically when you add the target to a load balancer.

I guess I don’t need to call this but error says that `attachToApplicationTargetGroup` is missing in type `InstanceIdTarget[]`.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `aws-cdk.aws-elasticloadbalancingv2-targets` package.

It also has an `IpTarget` construct.

You can also just use an instance target and point it to your instance:

`new InstanceTarget(instance: Instance, port?: number)`

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-elasticloadbalancingv2-targets.IpTarget.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-elasticloadbalancingv2-targets.InstanceTarget.html

**EDIT:** Regarding your edit, pass the array to `targets` and not an array with an array inside:

`targets: [pgAdminTarget],` should be `targets: pgAdminTarget`

Comment: Thank you so much. I got new error so I appreciate it if you cloud check it.

Comment: Thanks. I got another error:( `Type 'InstanceIdTarget[]' is not assignable to type 'IApplicationLoadBalancerTarget[]'.`

Comment: You probably have different versions of `aws-elasticloadbalancingv2` and `aws-elasticloadbalancingv2-targets` packages installed. 
Also, use `InstanceTarget`, it's cleaner.

Comment: Thank you so much. I could solve it by matching the version of packages.